# SSRS Rending Images From An External Web Server

Tags: reporting-services

We have a public website full of products. Each product has an image. The URL for the image is the product code so each image the URL is more or less https//images.company.com/1111/2222/111122223333.jpg. (where 111122223333 is the product code).

My database knows the product codes and I want to incorporate the product images into a report, pulled from the public website (which is hosted on a completely separate server).

On my SQL server, I can view the product images in the web browser without problem, however when I use the same URL as an image value in SSRS, I just get a red X and no image. I've tried storing the URL in a table and referencing the table to display the image but this just give me a blank image.

Is anyone able to advise whether what I'm trying to do is even possible and if so, where I might be going wrong? Using SQL Server 2014, SSRS 2012.

Comment: Make sure you image is set to External then try using a fixed image URL such as `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yaqe1qesQ8c/maxresdefault.jpg` If the fixed image works then it would guess it's an authentication issue. I've used external images before without any issues.

Comment: ALso pay attention to this warning about External images. `Warning  [rsWarningFetchingExternalImages] Images with external URL references will not display if the report is published to a report server without an UnattendedExecutionAccount or the target image(s) are not enabled for anonymous access.`

Comment: While checking the preview, try exporting the report as PDF, and see if the image is displayed as expected, or still you are getting the red X.

Comment: When I preview the report I'm getting two warnings. Warning 348 [rsInvalidExternalImageProperty] The value of the ImageData property for the image ‘Image2’ is “”, which is not a valid ImageData. E:\JASON_WORKSPACE\Reports\Report2.rdl 0 0